# Implementing the ResponseErrorHandler Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request

I'm trying to override the ResponseErrorHandler interface to be able to return the entire request (status code, body etc.) in case of any response other than 2xx.

I noticed that the Spring (RestTemplate) default returns an exception in case of a response other than 2xx. I do not want to return an exception, I just want to be able to return a:

`new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.STATUS_CODE)`

Following some tutorials, I've found the following code:

```
@Component
public class LoginErrorHandler
        implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {

        return (
                httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR
                        || httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode()
                .series() == SERVER_ERROR) {
            // handle SERVER_ERROR
        } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode()
                .series() == CLIENT_ERROR) {
            // handle CLIENT_ERROR
        }
    }
```

([Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling))

But I have not understood how I can return a ResponseEntity without changing the method return (which I can not by implementing the method).

Implementation:

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new LoginErrorHandler());

return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, String.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class LoginErrorHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public void handleError(HttpClientErrorException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(e.getRawStatusCode(), e.getStatusText());
    }
}
```

This you generify all status code that should drop an exception, and it will return in the body.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring's `ControllerAdvice` and `ExceptionHandler` annotations to handle exceptions through your application. Below code returns 500 http status code if any exception encountered in your request. You can add other Exception classes or your own custom class to handle specific cases and return specific status codes to client.

**Edit**

Handling each code will not be a good idea. Rather you can wrap them in your custom exception and provide proper message to your client service. Still you can try something like below.

```java
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Bad Request", value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handleBadRequest(HttpClientErrorException.BadRequest e) {

        //handle bad request exception
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Not Found", value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public void handleNotFound(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound e) {

        //handle Not Found
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Internal Server Error", value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public void handleInternalServerError(HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError e) {

        //handle internal server error
    }

//more methods for each code.
}
```

Then handle the codes from in your rest template as below. Here you won't be able to return body of the response to the client.

```java
@Component
public class LoginErrorHandler
        implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {

        return (httpResponse.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse)
            throws IOException {
        if (httpResponse.getRawStatusCode() >=400 && httpResponse.getRawStatusCode()<500 ) {
            throw HttpClientErrorException.create(httpResponse.getStatusCode(), httpResponse.getStatusText(), httpResponse.getHeaders(), null, null); 
        }else if(httpResponse.getRawStatusCode() >=500){
            throw HttpServerErrorException.create(httpResponse.getStatusCode(), httpResponse.getStatusText(), httpResponse.getHeaders(), null, null);
        }else {
            //throw some other exceptions for other codes and catch them in controller advice.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Nitin. Should I add a @ResponseStatus for every status code on the same method? Or I should use one method for one exception? Also, how should I use it on RestTemplate if it isn't a subclass of ResponseErrorHandler?

Comment: You need to use another methods for other Exceptions. You can not return multiple status codes for same exception.

Comment: I understand. Should I do something with the methods "hasError" and "handleError" that comes from ResponseErrorHandler?

Comment: So I don't need to use restTemplate.setErrorHandler(); ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two extensively used and very convenient exception handlers which are provided by Spring framework for centralized exception management in Spring Boot applications.

**ResponseEntityExceptionHandler :** exception thrown by our endpoint methods(methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`)

> A convenient base class for `@ControllerAdvice` classes that wish to provide centralized exception handling across all `@RequestMapping` methods through `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

[image]

**ResponseErrorHandler :** Spring provides a hook `ResponseErrorHandler` which can be implemented to handle the exception thrown by external services. To call any external service most likely you will be using a `RestTemplate`. A `RestTemplate` can throw three types of exception as listed below :

```
HttpClientErrorException : For 4xx series status codes or Client errors.
HttpServerErrorException : For 5xx series status codes or server errors
RestClientException : Any other status codes like 3xx series
```

To simplify things we can handle these exceptions as a catch block separately but it lead to lot of boilerplate code scattered across our service. Strategy interface used by the `RestTemplate` to determine whether a particular response has an error or not.

There are two steps to using `ResponseErrorHandler` :

Step 1: Create a custom error handler class by implementing `ResponseErrorHandler` and implements its methods `hasError` and `handleError`

[image]

Step 2: We need to inject the `ResponseErrorHandler` implementation into the `RestTemplate` instance as follows :
[image]
By default in `RestTemplate` the errorHandler points to `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`.

[Source](https://medium.com/@manishroy007/a-tale-of-two-exception-handlers-in-spring-boot-c678250a8242)